# Give error visual code editor and command prompt while ng serve

Tags: angular, angular-cli

file: 'file:///e%3A/ang-test/src/app/app.module.ts'

severity: 'Error'

message: 'Module '"e:/ang-test/node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MaterialModule'.'

Comment: which version of angular are you using?

Comment: Take a look upon [this discussion](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7692).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material-module'
```

also replace as mentioned in **[`changeLog`](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deprecation-of-md-prefix)**

**`Md*`** elements  with **`Mat*`**

in **`app.module.ts`**